# Populating QTableWidget with database values

Tags: c++, qt4, qtablewidget

In my GUI application, I want to populate a `QTableWidget` with values from Oracle DB. I know it is simpler to do using `QTableView` and `QSqlQueryModel`. But I want to access the data later on itemwise, hence I want to use `QTableWidget`.

I have successfully established connection to my oracle DB and the code snippet for populating data is --

```
QSqlQuery myquery("select SL_NO, NAME, AGE from EMPLOYEE");

ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(myquery.record().count());
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(myquery.size());

int index = 0;
while(myquery.next())
{
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(index,0,new QTableWidgetItem(myquery.value(0).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(index,1,new QTableWidgetItem(myquery.value(1).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(index,2,new QTableWidgetItem(myquery.value(2).toString()));
    index ++;
}
```

The output is --

[image]

What is wrong with my code ??? what am I missing ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I see for this effect is that myquery.size() in

> ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(myquery.size());

returns 0 and myquery.next() always returns false.

If myquery.size() were > 0 and myquery.value(0).toString() would return empty strings, you still would see the empty rows.

So I doubt that your query returns what you hope it returns.
Use some qDebugs to verify the data you get from your database.

Comment: well, the query is getting executed alright, there are no errors (db.lasterror)

Comment: i set if else control on query.exec() to see the error, but it came to qDebug success message, i.e. it did not come to the else clause containing db.lasterror

Comment: This does not mean that you get values. When the database connection is fine, you get an empty result. Nothing in EMPLOYEE?

Comment: right you are.. i was about to say that as well.. any process to see the o/p of query in console / qdebug ????

Comment: Can you execute this query directly in  Oracle? I do know nothing about Oracle, but it helped my more than once when I executed a query manually in a terminal for sqlite or postgresql.

Comment: in sqldeveloper it is getting executed properly.. its a common select query.. its returning all the desired records..

Comment: No idea. You could try the set the database directly in your QSqlQuery (second parameter). Or try "select * from EMPLOYEE". Just in case it is some capitalization problem. But from here I doubt I can help you much. What I can see from here looks fine.

Comment: You cold add for debugging reasons a: qDebug() << myquery.isActive();

Comment: i guess i should leave qtablewidget now and try using qtableview and try to separate the fields using loop variables.. thanks for your time and thoughts..

Comment: I am not sure that this will help. QTableView can also only show what the query returns. If you don't solve this problem, it would **really** surprise me if QTableView would show anything different.